# Вопрос по поиску в memo

Tags: delphi

Как реализовать поиск далее по memo при повторном нажатии кнопки?

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Find:string;
  i:integer;
begin
  find:='""';
for i:=0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
if Pos(FIND, Memo1.Lines.Text)<>0
then
begin
  Memo1.SetFocus();
  Memo1.SelStart:=Pos(FIND,Memo1.Lines.Text);
end;
end;
```

Comment: Возможно несколько вариантов. Попробуйте в цикле сравнивать значение pos(...) и selStart, например.

Answer (score 1):

Сохраняйте текущее положение (строку) в переменную и при новом поиске начинайте его с этого места (строки).

Если нужен последовательный поиск в той же строке, используйте `PosEx` он как раз принимает положение начала поиска.